# Pandas groupby agg std NaN

Tags: python, pandas, std, nan, pandas-groupby

Inputs:

```
df['PopEst']
    .astype('float')
    .groupby(ContinentDict)
    .agg(['size','sum','mean','std']))
```

Outputs:

```
            size            sum                mean              std
Asia          5     2.898666e+09       5.797333e+08     6.790979e+08
Australia     1     2.331602e+07       2.331602e+07              NaN
Europe        6     4.579297e+08       7.632161e+07     3.464767e+07
North America 2     3.528552e+08       1.764276e+08     1.996696e+08
South America 1     2.059153e+08       2.059153e+08              NaN
```

Some values in column of *std* turns out to be *NaN* if the group just have one row, but I think these values are supposed to be 0, why is that?

Answer (score 13):

[`pd.DataFrame.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) assumes 1 degree of freedom by default, also known as **sample** standard deviation. This results in `NaN` results for groups with one number.

[`numpy.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.std.html), by contrast, assumes 0 degree of freedom by default, also known as **population** standard deviation. This gives `0` for groups with one number.

To understand the difference between sample and population, see [**Bessel's correction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction).

Therefore, you can specify `numpy.std` for your calculation. Note, however, that the output will be different as the calculation is different. Here's a minimal example.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 9, (5, 2)))

def std(x): return np.std(x)

res = df.groupby(0)[1].agg(['size', 'sum', 'mean', std])

print(res)

   size  sum  mean       std
0                           
0     2   13   6.5       0.5
4     1    3   3.0       0.0
5     1    3   3.0       0.0
6     1    3   3.0       0.0
```

Alternatively, if you require 1 degree of freedom, you can use `fillna` to replace `NaN` values with `0`:

```
res = df.groupby(0)[1].agg(['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I change the code to `.agg('size','sum','mean',np.std)`, the _outputs_ still keep NaN. But when I use `lambda x:np.std(x)` instead, NaNs turn to 0, it is what I wanted. I wonder know why  this happened.

Comment: what if I want to be able to change `ddof` when calling `.agg([np.mean, np.std])`? I tried to pass it as external argument with `.agg([np.mean, np.std], ddof=0)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @FrancescoLS, As in my answer, use a function, e.g. `def std_zero(x): return np.std(x, ddof=0)`

Comment: @jpp yes, I see the point and it works. But what I am saying is that I want to be able to pass it as an argument, e.g. say I want to compare the `std` with `ddof` =1 and =2, doing as you suggest I would need to create 2 different functions and pass them

Comment: @FrancescoLS, The best I can think of.. you can use a higher order function via [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial), then use `partial(np.std, ddof=1)` or `partial(np.std, ddof=2)` etc.

Comment: @FrancescoLS why does return np.std(x, ddof=0) fix the problem? The default value of ddof is 0 in documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html

Comment: @torayeff my original problem was that I was getting different results because of the different defaults for ddof in pandas and numpy: in pandas ddof=1 and in numpy ddof = 0. So I was getting different result when using `groupby.agg(std)` and when doing `np.std(x)` in each group

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html), `np.std(..., ddof=1)` by default set "delta degree of freedom" to 1. To fix your problem, simply replace `np.std` with `lambda x: np.std(x, ddof=0)` then your `NaN` will be changed to `0`.

Comment: This answer seems incorrect.. the document linked refers to `pd.DataFrame.std` while the answer specifies it relates to `np.std`.